# How do I nest angular form attributes in a table?

Tags: angular, html-table, angular2-formbuilder

I am using angular form builder and I am trying to create a form inside a table. I have a list of parents, and each parent has a list of children, who each need a form.

My form builder looks like this:

```
let parentsModel: any[] = [
    {
        parentName: 'A',
        children: [
            {
                childName: 'AA',
                value: 1
            },
            {
                childName: 'AB',
                value: 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        parentName: 'B',
        children: [
            {
                childName: 'BA',
                value: 3
            }
        ]
    }
]

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    parents: this.formBuilder.array(
        parentsModel.map(parent => this.formBuilder.group({
            parentName: [parent.ParentName],
            children: parent.children.map(child => this.formBuilder.group({
                childName: [child.childName],
                value: [child.value, [Validators.required]],
            }))
        }))
    )
});
```

The problem is I am not sure how I would display this in a table with the form controls, since the "normal" way would be to nest divs such as:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="parents">
        <div *ngFor="let parent of parentsModel; let pIndex=index">
            <div [formGroupName]="pIndex">
                <div formArrayName="children">
                    <div *ngFor="let children of parent.children; let cIndex=index">
                        <div [formGroupName]="cIndex">
                            <!--form controls here-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My table currently looks like this (without referencing the form), so there is no way to nest elements in that way above since you cannot nest  or any other element inside a  element.

```
<table class="table table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Summary</th>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <ng-template ngFor let-parent [ngForOf]="parentsModel">
            <tr>
                <th scope="rowgroup" colspan="2">{{parent.parentName}}</th>
            </tr>
            <ng-template ngFor let-child [ngForOf]="parent.children">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{child.childName}}</td>
                    <td>{{child.value}}</td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I wondered about using ng-template, however that appears to only be usable for structural directives, is there another way to do this?

Comment: it is not necessary to use "div", you can use ng-container if you do not want to create additional html tags https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue or even, you can use "td" or  "tr" instead of" div "

Comment: @Eliseo I thought ng-container was also only supposed to be used with structural directives? I also didn't you could nest "tr" or "td"

Comment: @Eliseo Actually ng-container seems to work